# JSON.Parse Showing error at position 0 while parsing string to JSOn in Faker.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, faker

I have seen these type of questions and tried the solutions but was not working.

I am sending an array from UI to the controller, there I have the reference for faker.js in Node.js

My code in controller:

```
var FirstName = req.body;                    // req.body has array
console.log(FirstName);                      // **Prints** { FirstName: 'faker.name.firstName()' }
const User = FirstName;                     // Didnt work because faker.name.firstName is as string
const Usercheck = JSON.stringify(GettingData[0]);
var response = Usercheck.replace(/['"]+/g,'')
console.log(response);                      // Here it removed the quotations but took total as string. "{ FirstName: faker.name.firstName()}"
JSON.parse(response);     // Tried to parse string as JSON but this shows the error at position 0
```

The expected code for working in Faker.js is

```
const User = { FirstName: faker.name.firstName() } // Hard code and run this it is working fine
```

How to approach this.

Comment: `faker.name.firstName` is a function and needs to be evaluated

Comment: @GrégoryBourgin yes that's what if I get without that single quote (') it will work. Array may have still many fields like last name etc.,

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify add extra " around all keys, you can't remove them with Usercheck.replace(/['"]+/g,'') otherwise you can't parse it :

```
var a = JSON.stringify({e:5})
console.log(a) // {"e":5}

JSON.parse(a); // ok
JSON.parse("{e:5}"); // nok
```

Comment: here there is no number both are in characters(string). Here desired format is { e : sdfsfd} but i got like {e : 'sdfsfd'}

Comment: We don't care about the value, what i try to explain you its if you remove the " around the KEY which is in your case "FirstName", you will not be able to parse the string cuz it will not be a valid JSON anymore. In addition you can't store faker.name.firstName() in the value, you store the result of this call

Comment: ok, but I am getting value with a quotation. How to remove that quotation in value.

Comment: You can't its a string, if you want to interprete this string as a function you have to do something like this : var a =  { FirstName: 'faker.name.firstName()' }; var b = Function(a.FirstName)();